# In SQL, how can I achieve O(1) selects just like accessing an array in programming?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to store OHLCV daily data for stock prices. I thought about creating a table price_data which will include the fields: date, symbol, open, high, low, close, volume.

My question is: I understand that even if I use indexes, selecting from the database will take O(Log(N)). But how can I achieve O(1) speed?

Accessing arrays in any programming language takes O(1) because each element's size is known, so if you want to read the 5th element you just read array[5]. There should be something similar in database tables, right?

I can also assume that my data is incremental and each row is exactly 1 day after the next day (lets say crypto which trades 24/7), and if every row size is equal, technically it should be possible.

Its just weird that I google a lot and I cant find how to do it. it always leads to "use an index" and that the time to query a row will take Log(N). Even if i store each row in a different file on the hard disk, selecting from it will take O(1), so there must be some simple solution in SQL & databases.

A solution for sqlite will be optimal, but I'm interested in any general db/sql solution.

Comment: Where did you read that querying a row will take Log(N) ?? This question seems to suggest you disagree with the answers you already found but there is really no clarity on why you disagree and what you disagree with.

Comment: Querying a b-tree indexed column does take O(Log(N)), which is the index that sqlite creates. you can look at B-tree in wikipedia to confirm. You should read the question again, everything is included in the question.

Comment: I will say that in general, querying a database will be slower than accessing an array because a database is not an array. Array access is (ideally) direct access to an address in memory. Database access is ... well ... by working with a database. It is never going to be as fast as working with arrays directly in memory, even in the ideal situations (such as a database in memory).

Comment: I wasn't saying you were wrong - I just wanted clarification on what facts you are questioning. That's all, no offense intended. Since databases generally use B-Trees and B-Trees are not O(1) - you cannot get the performance you want from databases (as a general db/sql solution). But that's not normally why you use databases.